# What is an efficient alternative to iptables for bulk usage?

Tags: ip, iptables

Suppose I have a list of thousands of ip addresses to block. Right now I know how to iterate through the list and for each one run:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s XX.XX.XX.XX -j DROP
```

But this means I will have to run thousands of processes!

How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: Thousands of... _processes?_ What do you mean "processes"? Creating a list of firewall rules, saving the file, and then loading it on one or many hosts is how you do this.

Comment: I mean that I ask my shell to run the program `/usr/sbin/iptables` once for each address.

Comment: Can you direct me to a man page which describes the syntax of this list of firewall rules and how to load it on a host?

Comment: You may use "iptables-restore" but it will need all the rules in one shot, even the others chains

Comment: You just use `iptables-save` and pipe to a file, then `iptables-restore`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing what you should be doing. Create the rules, save the rules, then load the rules on each host that should have them. A possible refinement when using iptables for large lists of rules would be [IP Sets](https://ipset.netfilter.org/).

Comment: ipsets are a good use for this. They are very efficient, and once your iptables/ip6tables rules have been configured to reference them, you no longer need to play around with iptables rules. You can add/remove addresses from the referenced ipset on-the-fly very easily without having to reload anything.

Comment: Does this happen to be available as a Debian package?

Comment: @SeanLetendre IP Sets is a kernel module and should be available in basically all distros that use kernal 3.1 or greater. You shouldn't need to install anything.

Comment: Thank you. The tool to controls ipsets, "ipset" is needed as a separate Debian package even if the kernel contains the ipsets module.